# How can I inspect a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, internals

In jQuery 1.4.4, if I do this in Google Chrome's console:

```
var divs = $('div');
```

... what I get back appears to be an array of DOM elements. But I know it must be a jQuery object, because I can chain jQuery methods on it:

```
divs.hide('slow').show('slow'); // etc
```

What I want to see is the jQuery object, with a `.fn` property listing all its methods, etc. I'm pretty sure I used to be able to see this.

If I make my own object, like this:

```
var foo = {species: 'marmot', flavor: 'lemon'}
```

...I can dig into its properties in the console.

**How can I inspect the jQuery object in the console?**

Also, what magic is being done to make this look like an array?

### Update - it did change

If I load an old version of jQuery - for example, copy and paste this into my console in a blank tab:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js

... and I then do this:

```
var divs = $('div');
```

... I do get back `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init`, which I can dig into in the console. So something definitely changed since then.

Comment: I have edited my answer for Chrome. Have you had a chance to see if it worked or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1513378/1354978

Comment: Not universal but quite powerful: you can inspect/browse any Object with the Firebug console using  `console.dir(OBJECT_HERE);` or via the debugger

Answer (score 5):

I believe [this site](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/12/peeling-away-the-jquery-wrapper) describes what you're looking for in detail but to summarize (from the link):

> The interesting thing about the jQuery
> object is that while its datatype is
> an object, it has array-like
> characteristics:
>
> - its property names (the ones that    refer to DOM elements, at least) are
>   numeric
> - it has a length property

And: `$('div').toSource();` **Edit:** Only works in FF
Should be what you want for showing the properties of the object.

**For Chrome:**
[image]

Basically, you go to the Javascript Console in Chrome. Click on the Scripts tab (#1). Put a breakpoint on the spot where the code is you want to check (#2). Then run the script and when it breaks on that spot, check the scope variables (#3). Specifically the `__proto__` section.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'toSource'`

Comment: `toSource` isn't universal across browsers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101584/javascript-tosource-method-not-working

Comment: The article is also from 2008, a search on api.jquery.com for `toSource` doesn't find anything.

Comment: In Firebug, toSource() gives me something like: `({selector:"div", context:({}), 0:({}), 1:({}), 2:({}), 3:({}), 4:({}), 5:({}), 6:({}), 7:({}), 8:({}), 9:({}), 10:({}), 11:({}), 12:({}), 13:({}), 14:({}), 15:({}), 16:({}), 17:({}), length:18})`. Still not quite what I'm looking for - where is the `.fn` property?

Comment: @Nathan Long: Check out [this image](http://img577.imageshack.us/i/chrome.png/) I think that may be what you're looking for. Basically, you go to the Javascript Console in Chrome. Click on the Scripts tab (#1). Put a breakpoint on the spot where the code is you want to check (#2). Then run the script and when it breaks on that spot, check the scope variables (#3).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question in a very satisfying way, but it may help you, depending on what you're after:

I noticed that if you make the object less "array-like", then Chrome logs it as it would for a non-array object (i.e. with an expandable tree of properties).

One way to make it less array-like is to give the `length` property a non-numeric value:

```
var divs = $('div');
divs.length = "foo";
console.log(divs);
```

p.s. You'd probably want to set the object's `length` back to its original value before using it again.

Comment: Interesting and confusing. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this inspect function online one time and never looked back. It isn't jQuery though :/

```
function inspect(obj, maxLevels, level)
{
  var str = '', type, msg;

    // Start Input Validations
    // Don't touch, we start iterating at level zero
    if(level == null)  level = 0;

    // At least you want to show the first level
    if(maxLevels == null) maxLevels = 1;
    if(maxLevels < 1)     
        return '<font color="red">Error: Levels number must be > 0</font>';

    // We start with a non null object
    if(obj == null)
    return '<font color="red">Error: Object <b>NULL</b></font>';
    // End Input Validations

    // Each Iteration must be indented
    str += '<ul>';

    // Start iterations for all objects in obj
    for(var property in obj)
    {
      try
      {
          // Show "property" and "type property"
          type =  typeof(obj[property]);
          str += '<li>(' + type + ') ' + property + 
                 ( (obj[property]==null)?(': <b>null</b>'):('')) + '</li>';

          // We keep iterating if this property is an Object, non null
          // and we are inside the required number of levels
          if((type == 'object') && (obj[property] != null) && (level+1 < maxLevels))
          str += inspect(obj[property], maxLevels, level+1);
      }
      catch(err)
      {
        // Are there some properties in obj we can't access? Print it red.
        if(typeof(err) == 'string') msg = err;
        else if(err.message)        msg = err.message;
        else if(err.description)    msg = err.description;
        else                        msg = 'Unknown';

        str += '<li><font color="red">(Error) ' + property + ': ' + msg +'</font></li>';
      }
    }

      // Close indent
      str += '</ul>';

    return str;
}
```

Also console.log(obj) is cool, but I recently found another very cool function.
Try console.dir(obj), then in the console you will see that your obj will be a nice little node type structure which you will be able to look at all depth levels.
Try

```
console.dir(String)
// or  
obj = {'this' : 'that', 'one' : [2,3,4,5], 'A' : {} }; console.dir(obj)
```

Comment: Minor thing but it should be: `for (var property in obj)`

Comment: Thnx I added that. I think it is ok without though. It is a scope thing, and I think using it in the global variable space is ok here. It is a very interesting topic though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript